# using induction to prove $(n+1)^2 < 2n^2$

Tags: induction

(Im not English and just started doing maths in English so my termiology is still way off)

So the title for $n\ge 3$

1. First I use calculate both sides with $3$, which is true
2. I make my induction. $(k+1)^2 < 2k^2$
   then I replace $N$ with $k+1$:   $(k+2)^2 < 2(k+1)^2$

Now what? I cant seem to find how to use my induction in this one. I've also tried working out the brackets, but that also didn't seem to help me.

Comment: you can expand the LHS and RHS terms then use the induction step to prove the statement , i.e. $(k+2)^2=k^2+4k+4$ then see what happen with the other side ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: $(k+2)^2=\big((k+1)+1\big)^2=(k+1)^2+2(k+1)+1$; now apply the induction hypothesis that $(k+1)^2<2k^2$. (There will still be a bit of work to do; in particular, you’ll have to use the fact that $k\ge 1$.)

Comment: ((1.)) ((k+1)+1)^2 < 2(k+1)^2               

((2.)) (k+1)^2 + 2(k+1) + 1 < 2k^2 + 4k + 2               

((3.)) (k+1)^2 + 2k + 2 < 2k^2 + 4k + 2          

((4.)) then my hypothesis says (k+1)^2 < 2k^2 and 2k+2 < 4k+2         

right?

Comment: @Wouter: You’ve got some extra terms in there. All you need is $$(k+2)^2=(k+1)^2+2(k+1)+1<2k^2+2k+3<2k^2+4k+2$$ (since $k\ge 1$), and that last expression is $2(k+1)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(n+1)^2<2n^2\iff \left(1+\frac1n\right)^2<2$$

Let $P(n): \left(1+\frac1n\right)^2<2$

For $n=3,\left(1+\frac1n\right)^2=\left(1+\frac13\right)^2=\frac{16}9<2$

Let $P(n)$ is true for $n=m\ge3$ i.e., $\left(1+\frac1m\right)^2<2$

Now, as $m+1>m\iff \frac1m>\frac1{m+1}$ $\displaystyle \implies \left(1+\frac1{m+1}\right)^2<\left(1+\frac1m\right)^2<2$

So, $P(m+1)$ is true if $P(m)$ is true

Answer (score 1):

**1.Basis**

First we check for the smallest number: $n=3$

$$4^2 < 2*3^2$$
$$16 < 18$$

**2.Inductive Hypothesis**

$$(k+1)^2 < 2k^2$$

**3.Inductive step**

$$(k+2)^2 < 2(k+1)^2$$
$$k^2 + 4k + 4 < 2k^2 + 4k + 2$$
$$4 < k^2 + 2$$

Which is true for every $n \geq 3$

Comment: Very very clear...

Answer (score 0):

$(k+2)^2=(k+1)^2+2k+3$ and $2(k+1)^2=2k^2+4k+2$. Then by inductive hypothesis, $(k+1)^2<2k^2$, and for $k>0$, $2k+3<4k+2$. Thus you get $(k+2)^2<2(k+1)^2$.